# git amend added files in the staging area too

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

I had changed a lot of files and added them in the Git staging area. Then, before committing them, I realised that I had to change the commit message of the previous commit. So, I did a `git commit --amend` and changed the commit message without going through the change log. Well, that added the files in the staging area to the previous commit too.

What should I do so as to make the previous commit in its original form and get my changed files back in the staging area so I could commit them separately ?

For what it's worth, I realise that I should have committed my changes first and then changed the commit message history using `git rebase -i`.

Comment: Do you have unstaged changes?

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss No, I don't.

Comment: Do you still have the commit ID of the previous commit, somewhere? In that case you could *check* it *out*.

Comment: @opatut: That should be trivial to find out from the reflog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the SHA1 of the previous state of your previous commit using

```
git reflog
```

Using this hash, you can revert the current branch to it's previous state using

```
git reset --soft <SHA1>
```

After this, you can stash your changes, and then do `git commit --amend` to change the commit message.

Comment: Thanks :) Someday I'm gonna sit down and take out a couple of days and read everything about git. Someday.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the values of the commit id's in the reflog, do the following.

```
git reflog -5 #I assume this will be good enough; increase the value as needed
git reset --hard <commit-with-bad-message>
git commit --amend -m '<New message>'
git read-tree --reset -u <commit-that-had-extra-files>
```

You should now be where you wanted to be previously. Continue with your work.